# Finding multiple results in SQL Server 2012 (not duplicates)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need some help. I've got a list of customers and services that they've used, but I need to narrow that list to customers that have used more than one service (excluding those who've only used one service). They have sometimes used the same service more than once, but I need a list of unique services.

The below brings back the main list of customers.

```
SELECT
DISTINCT M.CustID
,S.ServiceID
,R.ReceivedDate
,S.ServiceRequestID

FROM Customers AS M

LEFT OUTER JOIN CustomerDates AS R ON M.CustID = R.CustID

LEFT OUTER JOIN Service1 AS S ON R.ServiceRequestID = S.ServiceRequestID

WHERE S.CloseDate IS NULL
```

[image: This is what the results look like]

What I need is a list that excludes the first three lines as they have only used one service, whereas the next seven I need as they've used more than one service.

Comment: Why are you using `SELECT DISTINCT`?  You should also include -- as *text* tables in the question -- what the tables look like.

Comment: Being honest, `SELECT DISTINCT` is a hangover from previous attempts that excluded many duplicates (DQ is currently awful).

And thank you - I'll include those next time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is quite likely that you can just use `NOT EXISTS`.  This is likely to do what you want:

```
SELECT M.CustID, S.ServiceID, R.ReceivedDate, S.ServiceRequestID
FROM Customers M JOIN 
     CustomerDates R
     ON M.CustID = R.CustID JOIN
     Service1 S
     ON R.ServiceRequestID = S.ServiceRequestID
WHERE S.CloseDate IS NULL AND
      EXISTS (SELECT 1
              FROM CustomerDates cd2
              WHERE cd2.CustId = m.custId AND cd2.ServiceRequestID <> r.ServiceRequestID
             );
```

I'm not 100% sure this is equivalent to your query.  The `SELECT DISTINCT` should not be needed, unless you have duplicates in your tables.  Also, you seem to require matches between the tables, so `LEFT JOIN` is not appropriate.  It it is not clear if the `WHERE` condition is relevant for finding duplicates.

Comment: This is it! Thank you very much. I needed to add a couple more joins to include everything I needed, and a `WHERE S2.CloseDate IS NULL`, but that cracked it - and even better, I learned something.

Thanks @Gordon!

Answer (score 0):

Try the following, it should work

```
SELECT
    CustID
    ,ServiceID
    ,ReceivedDate
    ,ServiceRequestID
FROM
(SELECT
    DISTINCT M.CustID
    ,S.ServiceID
    ,R.ReceivedDate
    ,S.ServiceRequestID
    ,count(*) over (partition by M.CustID) as total

FROM Customers AS M

LEFT OUTER JOIN CustomerDates AS R ON M.CustID = R.CustID

LEFT OUTER JOIN Service1 AS S ON R.ServiceRequestID = S.ServiceRequestID

WHERE S.CloseDate IS NULL
) vals
where total > 1
```

Comment: Thank you @zealous. This didn't work for me, but that's definitely down to data issues on my side.